# What is the woman saying in Itachi's theme song?

Tags: naruto, theme-song

When listening to Itachi's theme song, I heard that there is a woman voice in it, however I can't understand what it is saying. What is the woman saying in Itachi's theme song?

Comment: which do you mean by theme song?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is "asking for the lyrics of a piece of music, from a particular series or media". See https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and in particular, http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/453/should-we-allow-lyrics-request-and-lyrics-translation-of-a-certain-anime/454#454.

Comment: I edited the question since you said that you need it to understand what the woman says, which I suppose is your main point. Feel free to change it back if I edited it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

From Google, I found that Itachi's theme song is titled Senya (千夜, lit. Thousand Nights) and is part of [Naruto Shippuuden Original Soundtrack 2](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Music#Naruto_Shipp.C5.ABden:_Original_Soundtrack_II_.282009.29). [This song](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/narutoprofile/images/1/11/-Naruto_Shippuuden_Original_Soundtrack_2-_23_-_Senya.ogg/revision/latest?cb=20110913120142) has no lyric. The woman voice there is part of the instrument. If you listen to it carefully, the woman only voice the vocal "a".

According to [learntoplaymusic.com](http://www.learntoplaymusic.com/blog/why-the-human-voice-can-be-considered-the-ultimate-melodic-instrument/)

> the human voice can be thought of as the ultimate melodic instrument, because it is capable of instant expression with no instrument required to translate thoughts and feelings into sound.

The voice is there to give more feelings to the music about Itachi's pain, which just instruments won't be able to deliver.